# Separate interlaced elements with single loop

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function to separate interlaced elements.

```
interlacedElems :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
interlacedElems xs = (f xs, f $ tail xs)
   where f (x:_:xs) = x : f xs
         f x = x

main = print $ interlacedElems "a1b2c3d4"
```

Output produced:

```
("abcd","1234")
```

In my code I define `f` and use it twice, effectively recursing through the same list twice but slightly differently each time.

My question is: *is there a way I could write this so I only recurse through the list once?* Because that would be more efficient, don’t you think dawg?

I tried to figure it out my some of my brain leaked out and then my mom told me off because she says I’m always getting brain juice all over the place and it takes ages to get the pink stains out of the carpet.

Thank you nice people :)

Comment: Just want to address this: "Because that would be more efficient, don't you think?". My guess is "probably not, really" -- but you should definitely measure if that's something that matters to you! Check out [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) or something like it.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it using `foldr` using this trick:

```
interlacedElems :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
interlacedElems = foldr (\x ~(l,r) -> (x:r,l)) ([],[])
```

**Note**

The irrefutable pattern `~(l,r)` makes it work on infinite lists.

Comment: Neat. The only caveat is that, if it matters which sublist ends up with the first element of the original list, we need to tag the sublists.

Comment: @duplode it's easily provable that the first element will always end in the first list in the pair.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for making it clear for others :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just write a function that recursively splits a list into tuples and then use `unzip`:

```
listToTuples :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
listToTuples (x:y:xs) = (x, y) : listToTuples xs
listToTuples _ = []

interlacedElems :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
interlacedElems = unzip . listToTuples
```

Comment: Both the `unzip` and the explicitly recursive algorithm take ~n/2 steps, so I guess it matches the OP's request for a more efficient way. The only possible issue is that, if the original list has an odd number of elements, the last element is discarded.

Comment: @duplode I considered that, but I see no good way to solve that problem other than having a return type of `([(a, a)], Maybe a)`, which is too awkward to be worth it unless you really need that last element.